# Как Java используется на сайте без фреймворков. И как фронтенд взаимодействие с бэкендом

Tags: java, frontend

Хочу узнать как Java используется на сайте без фреймворков. И как фронтенд взаимодействует с бэкендом.

Answer (score 2):

Пишешь свой сервлет,  переопределяешь в нем   методы реквеста и респонса , в респонсе можешь написать фронт в поток  ,добовляешь сервлет в web.xml, конфигурационный файл твоего приложения, там ты можешь указать  к какому адресу привязан сервлет и многое другое.  Более продвинутый вариант это jsp - там ты грубо говоря пишешь фронт и в него вставляешь java код, ну  выглядит как в php код. Расписывать все это не вижу смысла. Есть книга Java servlet and JSP cookbook , там все есть. Да и вообще литературы по сервлетам хватает. Фреймворки  как раз строятся над сервлетам,  и дают тебе доступ к главному сервлету приложения, servlet context  . Тот же thymeleaf   работает через servlet context . Ну и забыл добавить, все это дело  без контейнера сервлетов работать не будет . Если самому с нуля написать веб сервер,  то для начала надо вам почитать про сокеты. Кст вопрос правильный, без понимания сервлетов , не будет понимания работы того же спринга